# How to apply additionalproperties: false to all object?

Tags: jsonschema

I created following json schema.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "hoge": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "code": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "foo": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "value": {
          "type": "number"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

When type is object, I want to set additionalproperties = false.
But this is very redundancy.

I defined following definitions to avoid duplicated additionalproperties, but it did not work as  expected.

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "baseObject": {
       "type": "object",
       "additionalProperties": false
    }
  },

  "allOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/baseObject"}],
  "properties": {
    "hoge": {
      "allOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/baseObject"}],
      "properties": {
        "code": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "foo": {
      "allOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/baseObject"}],
      "properties": {
        "value": {
          "type": "number"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to apply additionalproperties: false to type object ??

Comment: you are using JavaScript oder Jquery or in witch context you need to add this proprtie to all Objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With JSON Schema draft 2019-09 and above, you should use `unevaluatedProperties` as opposed to `additionalProperties` in your de-duplicated example schema.

`additionalProperties` can't "see through" applicator keywords like `$ref` or `allOf`. It's a little more complex than that, but that's the simplest way to think about it. `additionalProperties` works based on `properties` and `patternProperties` within the same schema object ONLY.